# Overusing Object.prototype.toString.call?

Tags: javascript

I just saw a [blog post](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/implementing-a-linked-list-in-javascript-3f71c83487b5) with the code

```
if(Object.prototype.toString.call(callback) !== '[object Function]'){
    return new TypeError(callback + ' is not a function');
};
```

In this specific situation it looks like over-engineering it since we could use `typeof callback`. I see no situation, for the purpose of this code, where `typeof callback` would not give the correct answer. Even more, the prototype could be overridden and start giving wrong answers while `typeof` can't.

Example would be:

```
Object.prototype.toString = function(){return '[Object String]';};
Object.prototype.toString.call([])
// logs "[Object String]"
```

**Question:** is there any situation (given the purpose of this line, which is to check if a variable is a function) where `typeof` would fail?

I think its more correct, semantic and not over-engineering to use:

```
if(typeof callback !== 'function'){
    return new TypeError(callback + ' is not a function');
};
```

Comment: `more correct` - that's an opinion :p but it's what I'd do

Comment: having said that, of course a generator function will result in typeof being 'function' - and since generator functions are so different from functions, chances are this would cause issues

Comment: Generator functions, async functions, and async generator functions are all still functions, @Bravo. The syntax for defining them is an implementation detail, and is deliberately not observable in a reliable way. They just happen to have specific return types — return types that any function could have regardless of whether it was written with specialized syntax. When you expect a function to, for example, return an iterable, the ‘type check’ for that return type occurs when you call the function and attempt iterating the result. It cannot be performed in advance, since it is just a contract.

Comment: Fair enough @semicolon - I haven't used generators in a very long time - of course you're right, the only thing that's different (when executing them) is the return type

Answer (score 3):

The Object.prototype.toString check is from the ES5 and earlier era, when the results of that method could not be forged through a custom Symbol.toStringTag implementation. However even then, if one wanted to be very strict about these tests, they would usually have had to grab a reference to the toString function at initial evaluation time, since Object.prototype.toString can itself be overwritten — as could Function.prototype.call.

Today it would never make sense to perform a type check this way, and you’re correct that even at the time, it wasn’t typically necessary. However in the past there were a number of platform objects in browsers that returned unique strings from typeof, and that was likely one of the motivations for performing a test this way. Today there is only one such weird case remaining: `typeof document.all` returns undefined, but it is actually a function.

Your instinct to prefer typeof is still correct, though. The case of document.all is probably not worth worrying about in almost any code, and even if it is, the toString check will not be reliable. An example of a real reliable (paranoid) check would be:

```js
var _Object = Object;

function isObject(value) {
  return _Object(value) === value;
}

function isFunction(value) {
  return typeof value === 'function' || (isObject(value) && typeof value === 'undefined');
}

console.log(isFunction(function() {})); // true
console.log(isFunction(document.all));  // true
```

So the answer to the part you marked ‘question’ is yes, there is one situation where typeof n === 'function' returns a misleading string, and historically there were additional situations.

---

More meta, regarding the ‘overengineering’ question: Perhaps the author learned it as a ‘best practice’ at some time in the past and hasn’t reviewed it in a while because, hey, it’s what’s familiar to them and it works, etc. Although there are better options, I wouldn’t call an awkward if condition overengineering. To me at least, overengineering refers to stuff at a higher level than this — architectural choices, etc. Things that are hard to refactor.

Personally, I would suggest that if you’re writing code that performs early input validation a lot, eschewing *direct* use of typeof might still be a good idea. Testing ‘types’ in JS is often not so straightforward, so a collection of `isSomething` functions like those in the example above can help abstract away the quirkier implementation details and bring some consistency and readability back. As functions, they’re also more flexible (e.g. `arr.filter(isFunction)`). There are popular libs that provide such utils and if using them you typically won’t need to worry about how it’s being achieved.